# Python: Iterate over files in directory and use the filenames as variables

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Dear stackoverflow users,

I'm struggling with figuring out the following problem:

I have a directory with multiple files such as

```
datasets/
    dataset1.txt
    dataset2.txt
    dataset3.txt
    dataset4.txt
    dataset5.txt
```

and to read out the files and assign their content to a variable that is their filename without the file type extension. To be explicit: The content of `dataset1.txt` should be saved to a variable `dataset1`, the content of `dataset2.txt` should be saved to the variable `dataset2` and so on.

I know that I can iterate over the content of my folder with the following function:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
print(files)
```

but at the end it should do something like the folling:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
for file in files:
file.split('.')[0] = numpy.loadtxt(file) # here it should create e.g. a variable dataset1 and read content of dataset1 into it.
```

How is this possible?

Regards,

Jakob

Comment: What type of variable do you want them to be? A list with each line in it?

Comment: The content of the files looks is a tabular seperated text file where the first column is my variable for the x-axis and the second column is my variable for the y-axis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use dictionary for this situation:

```
fileSet = {}

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
   for file in files:
      fileSet[file.split('.')[0]] = numpy.loadtxt(file)
```

Then you could access content with expression such as

```
dataset1Val = fileSet['dataset1']
```

Comment: That looks like a good solution. Just out of interest: is there a way to archieve this without a dictionary (even this wouldn't be as elegant)?

Comment: There might be. But in searching online, folks mostly prefer using dictionary than creating variables dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dictionary here. The advantage a dictionary would give you would be that

1. you could quickly access data in any file using a key.
2. To loop through the data from any all files, you don't need to do a lot of hardwork, instead you could just do `for key in my_file_dict.keys()`
3. To do a quick find for a text in a file, a dictionary would come in handy.

---

The below code, reads the data from a file, converts it into a list and then stores it to a `dictionary` with the `key` being the file name

To make it more **performance oriented**, you can use a `DictionaryComprehension` as well instead of the traditional nested `for loops`.

```
output_dict = {file.split('.')[0] : numpy.loadtxt(f'{directory_path}\\{file}').tolist() for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory_path) for file in files}
```

---

The traditional way:

```
output_dict = {}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        output_dict[file.split('.')[0]] = numpy.loadtxt(f'{path}\\{file}').tolist()
```